# Detach and re-attach mousewheel event listener don't reset scroll inertia

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent, mousewheel

I'm using the [jquery-mousewheel](https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel) plugin to trigger a function.

When I call *moveit* I detach the listener and wait until the animation is completed, then I re-attach the listener.

The problem is that when I re-attach it, the mousewheel plugin is still listening to the inertia of some mouses/trackpads, and call *moveit* repeatedly.

I guess debouncing or throttling the function call are not good solutions in my specific case, because the inertia is still there, and I also want the listener to be attached immediately for other possible *moveit* calls.

Is there a way to "kill the inertia" by completely resetting the mousewheel event, instead of only detaching it?

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var tween;
    var slide = $('#slide');

    function bodyListen () {
        $('body').on('mousewheel.bodyscroll',
        function (e, delta, deltaX, deltaY) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('body').off('mousewheel.bodyscroll');
            moveit();
        });
    }

    function moveit () {
        tween = TweenMax.to(slide, 0.8, {
            marginLeft: 300,
            onComplete: bodyListen
        });
    }

    bodyListen();
});
```

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: @dazhall unfortunately i had to adopt a workaround, like everybody do. i simply delayed the re-attachment of the mousewheel listener :(

Comment: Why don't just add a global flag instead of detaching the event listener? If the flag is on, the listener do nothing, else does what it have to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use flags when dealing with events (or any manipulation related to the DOM), beacuse event listener can often behave like asyncronous functions.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var tween;
    var slide = $('#slide');
    var flag = true;

    function bodyListen () {
        $('body').on('mousewheel.bodyscroll',
        function (e, delta, deltaX, deltaY) {
            if(flag){
                e.preventDefault();
                flag = false;
                moveit();
            }
        });
    }

    function moveit () {
        tween = TweenMax.to(slide, 0.8, {
            marginLeft: 300,
            onComplete: function(){
                flag = true;
            }
        });
    }

    bodyListen();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I have not tried this myself, TweenMax has [Kill Tweens of](https://www.greensock.com/as/docs/tween/com/greensock/TweenMax.html#killTweensOf) and [KillAll](https://www.greensock.com/as/docs/tween/com/greensock/TweenMax.html#killAll%28%29) that allow you to kill a tween and optionally complete them before you do. maybe not what you want, because it would force the animation to finish but it gets you back to a state you want and the code insert is simple. At the beginning of function bodyListen

```
function bodyListen() {
    if(tween) tween.killAll(true)
    .....
```